# Is there any selenium browser options to remove local user account data shown edge browser in automation testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, microsoft-edge-chromium

When I try to perform automated login using edge chromium browser by selenium , by default the edge chromium browser of automation instance takes the logged user data in edge browser instance and displaying the users, Is there any browser options or capabilities that would disable user data being shown when running selenium tests in edge chromium browser

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L8q1.png

Answer (score 0):

try this if something does not work out, write to us and we will think further
[https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=cookie#:~:text=the%20specified%20element_id.-,delete_all_cookies,-()%C2%B6](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=cookie#:%7E:text=the%20specified%20element_id.-,delete_all_cookies,-()%C2%B6)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I have gone through the article but I couldn't able to find any ways to remove the user data accounts when performing automated login test.